# No activity detected on VM, aborting (Docker inside Win10 VM)

Tags: docker, vmware, hyper-v

I'm want to run Docker inside my Win10 Pro VM (running via VMWare on a Win10).
Docker for Windows runs fine with Windows containers enabled, but if I switch to Linux containers I get this exception:

```
No activity detected on VM, aborting
   bei Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:Zeile 36.
   bei Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:Zeile 78.
   bei Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<ResetToDefault>b__0() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:Zeile 138.
   bei Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:Zeile 59.
```

I tried many different things:

- on my host system Hyper-V is disabled and enabled on my VM
- different Docker for Windows Versions(stable and edge)
- resetted Docker to factory settings a few times
- played with VM Settings

What could cause the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: This issue does not have to be caused by your running of docker within a VM. Other people (including me) experienced it with Docker running directly in their Windows 10 instance. See also [Docker for windows issue #2061](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2061) (Closed), or [issue #2253](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2253) (Still Open).

Comment: But still no solution.

Comment: did you get a solution for this? I am badly stuck on this issue... :(

Comment: A few updates later and a lot of research...still no solution. I stopped using Docker for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Linux containers on Windows VM or host?

It will not work, as docker need the same kernel on host. In reality all docker container processes will be running in host kernel so need to have same kernel. Run Linux VM on windows and then run docker containers on Linux VM, it will work but you can't run Linux containers on Windows or Windows containers on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Docker for Windows with Linux containers a Linux VM is used in the background that actually runs the Linux containers.

So what you are doing is called nested virtualization, which has different requirements that you must meet.

In addition, you mix the two hypervisors VMware and Hyper-V, which could also be problematic.

One possible solution or workaround is to directly run a Linux VM in your VMware environment instead of your Windows 10 VM.

Sources:

- [Linux containers on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers)
- [VMware vs Hyper-V Nested Virtualization](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2018/07/vmware-vs-hyper-v-nested-virtualization/)